# Mockery/Etsy PHPExtensions does not fail test if required methods are not called

Tags: php, unit-testing, tdd, phpunit, mockery

I have the below code, which I would expect to fail when run as the class `DoesNothing` doesn't use the mock class or call any of the required methods on it.

```
<?php
class DoesNothing
{

}

class DoesNothingTest extends YourMockeryTestCase
{
    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function somethingIsCalled()
    {
        $this->mock = Mockery::mock();

        $keys = array(
            '1234',
            'abcxyz',
            '*&(%&^$-*/~@:{}',
            ')*&GA^FAUIB(*',
            '',
            ' ',
        );

        foreach ($keys as $key) {
            $this->mock
                ->shouldReceive('remove')
                ->atLeast()->times(1)
                ->with($key);
        }
        $var = new DoesNothing($this->mock);
    }
}
```

But when I run it, it passes. I would expect it to say "method remove was not called" etc.

What could be wrong? Something to do with how Mockery Talks to PHPUnit?

Thanks,
 Martin

Edit:
I shoudl also mention we are using [Etsy's PHPExtensions](https://github.com/etsy/phpunit-extensions/wiki/Mockery) to integrate it into PHPUnit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your method name should start with `test`, otherwise PHPUnit will not determine it as test.

```
public function testSomethingIsCalled()
```

**edit**

You have to call `Mockery::close()` in your teardown method for expectations to be executed. i.e.

```
/**
 * Tear down
 */
public function tearDown()
{
    \Mockery::close();
}
```

Comment: The phpDoc syntax lets PHPUnit know it's a test without the prefix Documentation here: http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.annotations.html (scroll to bottom)

Comment: @Martin Lyne, didn't know that. You learn something new every day ;). Try adding an assertion in your test to be 100% sure your test is at least executed correctly.

Comment: :) And yeah, I just added `$this->assertTrue(false)` and it picks up the failure, unfortunately. :(

Comment: We have a winner! I thought the Etsy stuff removed the need for that, but I was wrong. The most annoying part is that I had that there in the beginning and removed it. What a fool! Thanks Bram.

Comment: http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/phpunit_integration.html To integrate Mockery, you just need to define a tearDown() method for your tests containing Mockery::close()